# springboot unable to convert ZonedDatetime to json response in more readable way

Tags: json, spring-boot, java-8, jackson

I am trying to convert an object containing `ZonedDatetime` to json response. 
The json response I get is as below

```
{
    "DateTime": {
        "offset": {
            "totalSeconds": 19800,
            "id": "+05:30",
            "rules": {
                "transitionRules": [],
                "transitions": [],
                "fixedOffset": true
            }
        },
        "zone": {
            "id": "Asia/Calcutta",
            "rules": {
                "transitionRules": [],
                "transitions": [
                    {
                        "offsetBefore": {
                            "totalSeconds": 21208,
                            "id": "+05:53:28",
                            "rules": {
                                "transitionRules": [],
                                "transitions": [],
                                "fixedOffset": true
                            }
                        }
```

How to convert this response to a specific format, say "dd::MM::yyyy".

I tried using date formatter in object mapper but didn't work as expected.

```
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
        return objectMapper;
```

Also tried using @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd::MM::yyyy") annoation. Didnt give the result.

```
public class Response {
    @JsonProperty(
            value = "DateTime",
            required = false
    )
    @XmlElement(
            name = "DateTime",
            required = false
    )
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd::MM::yyyy")
    private ZonedDateTime dateTime;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't return a `String` instead of `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: Could you please post the whole `JSON` which represents date? Above one is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `jackson-datatype-jsr310` as a dependency. This module contains serializers and deserializers for all the `java.time` classes, and those should also support specifying a custom pattern.

The default `ObjectMapper` configured by spring-boot should pick up this module automatically from the classpath.

If you configure your `ObjectMapper` yourself you need to register the module

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")` or `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")` formats without any configuration? The Spring's default `ObjectMapper` should (and will) handle this. `ZonedDateTime` will accept ISO date time formats which can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in detail.

**Note:** If you do not care about the Zone (Eg: `Asia/Calcutta`), you can use `OffsetDateTime` which will give you the *Zone Offset* like `+05:30` and the same (above) pattern can be used.